# Node.js with Git Bash (MINGW64)

Tags: node.js, bash

I'm running windows. I just updated node.js with the MSI installer. I always used node with git bash for running commands. But after the upgrade, the node version in git bash didn't change:

```
$ node -v
v0.11.14
```

if I run in cmd, it shows a different version:

```
$ node -v
v4.3.1
```

I checked the $PATH in git bash and it points to the right location (c:\Program Files\nodejs)

what could be the problem?

Comment: Could you run `where node` in both terminal ?

Answer (score 0):

Mingw adds own prefixes to PATH variable. Use:

```
whereis node
```

to find where is version Mingw starts.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem could be, because of some additional configs set in `.profile` or `.bashrc` files, that are located in your user's home directory e.g. `c:\users\gevorg\`.

To find why `Git Bash` loads wrong version of Node.js just run `$ where node` from it and locate old executable location.